# How to access current php file in php extension (written in c)?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I'm trying to write an extension for php using swig. I need to know the absolute path of the current php file in my extension code. I used __ FILE __ in my C code but it returns current c file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found the solution. to access __ FILE __ in your php extension, you can use like this:

```
char *file_name = zend_get_executed_filename();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the realpath() function. Specify the name of your current file.

hint: man 3 realpath or http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=realpath&sektion=3

Comment: I dont know the current file name. it might be any file of my project. by the current file name i mean the php file that called the extensions function.

Comment: If the OP already knew `pathname` he wouldn't need this function ;-)